# Access Docker inside Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a pretty specific use-case for a development environment. In some code, I spin up a container to scrape a page and retrieve a token of a service(Gitlab) running in a container.

Now, I wish to Dockerize the code that runs this. Specifically, something like:

```
out, err := exec.Output("docker", "run", "--net=host", "--rm", "-e", "URL=http://127.0.0.1:8081", "-e", "USER=root", "-e", "PWD=adminadmin", "some image")
```

However, when running this inside a container, obviously my code throws `panic: exec: "docker": executable file not found in $PATH` as `docker` is not recognized inside the container.

How do I install Docker inside a Docker container? Can I somehow bind it from the host? Should this happen in the `Dockerfile`, or can I define such behavior via the `docker-compose.yml` file I use to spin it up?

I am on OSX. Output of `which docker` is `/usr/local/bin/docker`

Comment: @atline I feel as if the case isn't exactly 1:1 here; I'm trying to do it from either the Dockerfile itself or docker-compose, not via `docker run`

Comment: yes, but `-v` in docker run could be traslated to `volumes: -/var/sock:/var/sock` in docker-compose.

Comment: For the suggestion, adding `"$(which docker):/usr/bin/docker"` to volumes gives ` Invalid interpolation format for "volumes" option in service`

Comment: You run it in compose? If in compose, please use `/usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker`

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant with my very first comment

Comment: please use /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker

Comment: That leaves me with `'Mounts denied: \r\nThe path /usr/bin/docker\r\nis not shared from OS X and is not known to Docker.`

Comment: Wow, you are in mac?

Comment: I am indeed. Should've mentioned that, sorry :)

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/local/bin/docker` does also not work(that is the output of `which docker` :)

Comment: Yes, it's so important...  Let me check later, or you can wait others.

Comment: So, I just manage time to have a try on a mac, it seems work, see my update answer, could you double check you use the same?

Answer (score 2):

yeah, it is possible, its called docker in docker, or DinD.

dont even mind installing docker yourself - docker has an [official dind image](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) with a wide range of tags.

Comment: How would I bake this into an existing Golang image and have access from it? `FROM golang:1.10`?

Comment: i personally recommend you to re-structure your dockerfile - use a dind base image (alpine-based is recomended) and then install golang by yourself.

Comment: It's worth a read of this: https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/ Written by a docker dev.

Answer (score 1):

So, I just tried on a mac with `docker for windows`:

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: ubuntu:16.04
    volumes:
      - /usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/local/bin/docker
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    command: docker version
```

**Execution:**

```
MAC-MINI:try guest$ docker-compose up
Starting try_app_1 ... done
Attaching to try_app_1
app_1  | Client: Docker Engine - Community
app_1  |  Version:           18.09.2
app_1  |  API version:       1.39
app_1  |  Go version:        go1.10.8
app_1  |  Git commit:        6247962
app_1  |  Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:11:44 2019
app_1  |  OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
app_1  |  Experimental:      false
app_1  |
app_1  | Server: Docker Engine - Community
app_1  |  Engine:
app_1  |   Version:          18.09.2
app_1  |   API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
app_1  |   Go version:       go1.10.6
app_1  |   Git commit:       6247962
app_1  |   Built:            Sun Feb 10 04:13:06 2019
app_1  |   OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
app_1  |   Experimental:     false
try_app_1 exited with code 0
```

It seems all ok to use the docker daemon also the docker client of host.

And if you mind to use the `docker client` which mounted from host, you could also use static binary, see [how to install static binary](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/binaries/#install-static-binaries)

**UPDATE:**

Also, I try to run a real container not just `docker version` like next:

```
services:
  app:
    image: ubuntu:16.04
    volumes:
      - /usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/local/bin/docker
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    command: docker run --rm hello-world

It's still ok as next:

$ docker-compose up
Recreating try_app_1 ... done
Attaching to try_app_1
app_1  | Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
app_1  | latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
app_1  | 1b930d010525: Pulling fs layer
app_1  | 1b930d010525: Download complete
app_1  | 1b930d010525: Pull complete
app_1  | Digest: sha256:6540fc08ee6e6b7b63468dc3317e3303aae178cb8a45ed3123180328bcc1d20f
app_1  | Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest
app_1  |
app_1  | Hello from Docker!
app_1  | This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.
app_1  |
app_1  | To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
app_1  |  1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
app_1  |  2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
app_1  |     (amd64)
app_1  |  3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
app_1  |     executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
app_1  |  4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
app_1  |     to your terminal.
app_1  |
app_1  | To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
app_1  |  $ docker run -it ubuntu bash
app_1  |
app_1  | Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
app_1  |  https://hub.docker.com/
app_1  |
app_1  | For more examples and ideas, visit:
app_1  |  https://docs.docker.com/get-started/
app_1  |
try_app_1 exited with code 0
```

**2rd update according to @PierreB 's suggestion to add more about how to use static binary:**

1. Download from https://download.docker.com/, choose one package which suitable for your target image, e.g if target image is linux, then download from [here](https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/).
2. Unpackage the binary to current folder, you could see docker client with the name `docker`, it's a standalone binary.
3. Change docker-compose.yaml to next to mount this static binary from host to container:

   ```
   services:
     app:
       image: ubuntu:16.04
       volumes:
         - ./docker:/usr/local/bin/docker
         - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
       command: docker run --rm hello-world
   ```

Comment: -1 for that `/usr/local/bin/docker` mount: you should not mount binaries like this, lots of dependencies may be needed. Even though `docker version` works this way, there is no guarantee a real usage would work. +1 for static binaries install though, you may be more precise on how to achieve this

Comment: @PierreB. Yes, I also doubt directly mount the binary from osx to linux will have some issue. But failed to find which will be issue, did you have any example?

Comment: @PierreB. You can see even I run a real container, it's still ok. Do you have any example which will have issue. I also have this concern, could you teach me?

Comment: This is more about mouting a biinary file from the OS directly into another OS. It may work with the few examples you provided, specifically on MacOS host to Ubuntu 16.04 container, but it may not in other situations. I do not have specific example, but Docker is more than just a binary: you'll need a lot of libraries and system configuration for it to work properly. I'll try to provide one.

Comment: @PierreB. Yes, sure, it won't work for windows, also maybe not work for alpine. I will update static binary solution, just curious how it work as `otool -L /usr/local/bin/docker` also show some dependency.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different things happening here :

- You will need a docker client inside your golang container
- You will need a reachable docker daemon (server)

In order to install the client in your running container, as you seem to use the golang image which is debian-based you can just : `apt-get update && apt-get install -yq docker`

At this point, if you try to execute the `docker run` command you will get something like :

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
```

This means you will now have to provide the docker client a working docker server. This can be done by running another container next to it (known as a service) running `dind` (docker in docker) as said in [Efrat Levitan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57070391/7906071). You will then have to define the variable `DOCKER_HOST: tcp://<docker_server_address>:2375/` The address will depend on your setup and how you started the containers.

Another way can be mouting the host docker socket (not advised as it may cause data corruption).

To understand the implications you may want to read [Jérôme Petazzoni's article](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/) about docker in docker.